# Why in Intellij IDEA presence of ENQ/ESA unicode character in code cause it to show false multiple character literals error?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, unicode, intellij-plugin, lexer

I was trying to fix some weird PDF Unicode remapping issues when I was stuck by this issue where adding an [ENQ Unicode](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0005#UNC_DB) character to some part of the code prevents you from compiling the code and IDE will present you with what I think is a false alarm(error).

Consider this example of [completely valid Kotlin code](https://pl.kotl.in/5OoTbMUMH) and let's call it **Program A** where unfortunately you can't see the actual characters here between apostrophes but believe me there's a character in there (if you copy this code into your IDE you can see those characters).

```kotlin
package yamin

fun main() {
    val foo = mutableListOf('')
    //val bar = mutableListOf('')
    println(foo)
}
```

However, you can see them in the picture.

[image: Program A]

But if you decide to compile this code somehow IDE fails to compile it and claims that there are '**Too many characters in a character literal**' in **line 4**.

[image: Program A false error]

What is interesting is that the sheer presence of ENQ character even in a comment line prevents the IDE to compile this code and if you remove **line 5**, therefore, removing the presence of **ENQ character** then you can compile this code (let's call it **Program B**), observe:

[image: Program B]

Anyway if you decide to **remove line 4** in **Program A** and **uncomment line 5** then you can compile that code too (let's call it **Program C**).

[image]

So let's recap Program A is invalid and line 4 is the culprit of the invalidity but removing line 5 in that program which leaves us with Program B could be compiled successfully and this situation is repeated for Program C.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you literally have 'ESA' wrapped in single quotes? B/c I don't see that ever compiling for me. I believe character literals can only have more than one character if you begin with an escaping backslash. 

Otherwise, looks like something you could report to Kotlin Issue Tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT.

Comment: @Trevor I already did.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-281164

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a bug in Kotlin compiler, because the error happens even if the code is compiled with command-line:
`kotlinc enq.kt -include-runtime -d enq.jar`

Also, [this simple program](https://pl.kotl.in/WmF6XjI-A) gives different results on the playground (correct):

[image]

and locally (incorrect):

[image]

As a workaround you may use Unicode escape sequence syntax (at least for ENQ symbol):

[image]

Playground does the same thing when passing this code to the server, so the compiler gets sanitized code:
[image]

Comment: You're right I can work my around it by escaping it but I don't see why original code is not compilable in IntelliJ IDEA. I don't know it's a bug in Kotlin plugin, IDE itself or even something I do is fundamentally wrong.

Comment: Updated my answer, to clarify that it's a bug in a Kotlin compiler (and explaining why it works on playground)